# No network access due to WLAN0:AVAHI

Tags: networking, wireless

I have a laptop with Ubuntu 11.04. Failed to connect my home wireless network, which is composed of a modem and a Netgear router.

ifconfig showing:

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:24:d6:07:2b:a2  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:30238 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:24005 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:26945081 (26.9 MB)  TX bytes:3169731 (3.1 MB)

wlan0:avahi Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:24:d6:07:2b:a2  
          inet addr:169.254.6.188  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

iwconfig showing :

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"mywirelessnetwork"  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

I do not quite understand how the virtual interface wlan0:avahi appeared. My guess was, my request `sudo dhclient wlan0` failed to get a valid ip, although I did not get any error message from running that command. I executed `sudo dhclient wlan0` again, but still no error message or network connection.

Later today, I tried to connect to a public wireless network. Still got the same error. But when I reboot my machine, no such problems.

I am confused by the wired situations. Is there anything wrong with my network configuration? What should I do if I encounter similar problems in future?

Answer (score 2):

May I suggest that you run the command

```
cat /etc/network/interfaces
```

This will show the contents of the interfaces file. It should read

> auto lo
>
> iface lo inet loopback

If there is anything else in this file then edit it out by this command

```
gksudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

This will open the interfaces file in gedit with sudo permissions. So you can edit the file and save it. I had to do this once when I somehow got wlan0:avahi as the wireless connection and I could not remove it any other way. You may need to re-start and then Network manager will do its stuff.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks! But my interfaces file does not have anything else except "auto lo iface lo inet loopback". I am afraid that something else is going wrong. BTW, I am not using Network Manager. I set up wireless connection via command line.

Answer (score 1):

Usually when you are getting such an avahi interface either your router or your own network card is not ready (or even has a problem) for some reason.

In my case I solve this quickly with either:
`sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0`
or
`sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`

ps: [this question is related.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3159/delete-eth0-avahi-from-the-ifconfig-list/72778#72778)